# how to modify text color/weight in an MVVM WPF framework

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a textbox that I am updating through an mvvm framework.

the viewmodel is simple enough

```
StringBuilder status_messages = new StringBuilder();
object obj_lock = new object();

public String StatusMessages { get { return PrintStatusMessages(); }}

void UpdateStatusMessages(string message)
{
    lock(obj_lock)
    {
         status_messages.Append(Message);
         OnPropertyChanged("StatusMessages");
    }
}

string PrintStatusMessages()
{
    lock(obj_lock)
    {
         return status_messages.ToString();
    }
}
```

and the textbox in the view is bound on the StatusMessages property.

I would like to highlight certain lines of text dependent on some logic. 
For example:

if the contents of status_messages are:

```
VERY IMPORTANT: blah blah blah blah 
NOT IMPORTANT: bajksdfds;afkjdsa
NOT IMPORTANT: fdskafdjsafjewa
```

I would like the VERY IMPORTANT line to be highlighted. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: I think you are looking for [Converters](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) - if you don't want to have it in the Viewmodel or if you need the conversion often they are what you'll want

Comment: to your further remarks: **I** would parse this text into a internal representation (close to XAML/HTML - meaning the *important* blocks already selected/parsed) and then use this representation to render XAML in a `TextBlock` - so you have two subproblems here neither of which *I* will code for you from scratch as they are way to broad

Comment: A string is a string is always a string.  However, `abstract class Message` can be a `class NormalMessage : Message` or a `class ImportantMessage : Message`.  Then you bind to a collection of `Message`s and control display of each via a `DataTemplate`--one for normal messages, one for important ones.  And that's how MVVM works.  The Aristocrats.

Answer (score 0):

I think that best approach here is to use more properties in your viewmodel. Since, not all lines of your message are equal (some are more important) that's ok from the pattern-side. ]

So it should be something like that:

```
public string ImportantMessages { get; set; }
public string NotImportantMessages { get; set; }
```

Or it's even better to use `ObservableCollection<>` since different lines can posess different meaning. And use separate class for you messages.

```
public class StatusMessage//:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool IsImportant { get; set; }
}
```

In your VM:

```
public ObservableCollection<StatusMessage> { get; set; }
```

Bind this collection to any ItemsControl(ListView, ListBox ...) in XAML and set ItemTemplate that you want.

In your view you are free to use different templates, ValueConverters for FontSize, Adorners, AttachedProperties or whatever you want to change text appearance depending on IsImportant.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [valueconverters](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/)

They contain the logic. If your logic needs more than one value to base its logic you can use [multivalueconverters](http://blog.csainty.com/2009/12/wpf-multibinding-and.html)

Comment: I mentioned that I would like only certain lines of text to be particularly highlighted. I was under the impression that a valueconverter would not be able to do this. Was I mistaken?

Comment: @cubesnyc no you are not - but you did not give anything specific - I think in this case it's best to use a viewmodel for your highlighted text and a `TextBlock`